# OpenCV imread issue

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm compiling a simple project on VS2012 with OpenCV 2.4.7.

So when I do:

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("C:\lena.jpg",1);
```

Then I looked for a solution for the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion Failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in unknown function
```

So, I put this:

```
IplImage* img1 = cvLoadImage("C:\lena.jpg", 1);
Mat img(img1);
```

And it works well. Is this just only one solution?

PS: I had the same problem on Ubuntu, and I tried changing the path in different ways.

Comment: Which function gives you the exception, is it `imread(…)`? Can it be that the error is in some other function? did you try `"C:/lena.jpg"` as path to `imread`?

Comment: The error is in imread, because I replaced it with IpL way, and as I mentioned it works well... And yes, I tried with `C:/lena.jpg` but did not work :-\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of your escape sequencing. Look at the below path:

```
C:\\Users\\name\\Pictures\\Dell WebCam Central\\img.jpg
```

This will compile normally, as will

```
C://Users//name//Pictures//Dell WebCam Central//img.jpg
```

However, with improper escape sequencing, as you had used, then the assertion will fail.

See [escape sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) for more information.